# Structured Streaming: Streaming Exception on restarts due to checkpoint data

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-2.0

I have one read stream to consume data from a Kafka topic , and based on an attribute value in each of the incoming messages, I have to write data to either of the 2 different locations in S3 (if value1 write to location1, otherwise to location2).
On a high level below is what I have for doing that,

```
Dataset<Row> kafkaStreamSet = sparkSession 
            .readStream() 
            .format("kafka") 
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBootstrap) 
            .option("subscribe", kafkaTopic) 
            .option("startingOffsets", "latest") 
            .option("failOnDataLoss", false) 
            .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", offsetsPerTrigger) 
            .load(); 

    //raw message to ClickStream 
    Dataset<ClickStream> ds1 = kafkaStreamSet.mapPartitions(processClickStreamMessages, Encoders.bean(ClickStream.class));
```

ClickStream.java has 2 child objects  within it  and only one of them will be populated at a time depending on if the message attribute value is  either value1 or value2,

1) BookingRequest.java if  value1,
 2) PropertyPageView.java if value2 ,

which I then separate  out as below from clickstream to write to 2 diff locations in S3,

```
    //fetch BookingRequests in the ClickStream 
    Dataset<BookingRequest> ds2 = ds1.map(filterBookingRequests,Encoders.bean(BookingRequest.class)); 

    //fetch PropertyPageViews in the ClickStream 
    Dataset<PropertyPageView> ds3 = ds1.map(filterPropertyPageViews,Encoders.bean(PropertyPageView.class));
```

finally  ds2 and ds3 are written to 2 different locations ,

```
   StreamingQuery bookingRequestsParquetStreamWriter = ds2.writeStream().outputMode("append") 
        .format("parquet") 
        .trigger(ProcessingTime.create(bookingRequestProcessingTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) 
        .option("checkpointLocation",  "s3://" + s3Bucket+ "/checkpoint/bookingRequests") 
        .partitionBy("eventDate") 
        .start("s3://" + s3Bucket+ "/" +  bookingRequestPath); 



    StreamingQuery PageViewsParquetStreamWriter = ds3.writeStream().outputMode("append") 
        .format("parquet") 
        .trigger(ProcessingTime.create(pageViewProcessingTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) 
        .option("checkpointLocation",  "s3://" + s3Bucket+ "/checkpoint/PageViews") 
        .partitionBy("eventDate") 
        .start("s3://" + s3Bucket+ "/" +  pageViewPath); 

    bookingRequestsParquetStreamWriter.awaitTermination(); 

    PageViewsParquetStreamWriter.awaitTermination();
```

it seems to work  fine and I see data written to different paths when the apps deployed. But, whenever the job is restarted on failure or on manual stops and starts, it keeps failing with below exception (where userSessionEventJoin.global is my topic name),

Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: Expected e.g. {"topicA":{"0":23,"1":-1},"topicB":{"0":-2}}, got {"userSessionEventJoin.global":{"92":154362528,"101 org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.JsonUtils$.partitionOffsets(JsonUtils.scala:74) 
        org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceOffset$.apply(KafkaSourceOffset.scala:59)

if I delete all the checkpointing information, then it starts again and starts new checkpointing in the given 2 locations, but that means I have to start processing from the latest offset again and lose all previous offsets. 
The spark version is 2.1, and this topic has 100+ partitions.
I tested with just one writestream (one checkpoint location), same exception happens on restarts.

Please suggest any resolutions, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your code is a simple click stream job. In your example you create a spark streaming session and use the checkpoint directory to intermittently store checkpoint data.

Your code however does not know how to hydrate from a checkpoint.

It will be clear by the end of this paragraph.

Here is the steps for a production level streaming job.

```
1) Use getOrCreate API to create your spark streaming session.
   a) getOrCreate takes two parameters. A function "(....) => sparkSession" and the checkpoint directory.
2) When program starts for the first time, it uses the checkpoint directory to store it's inner details. (Among other uses)
3) When program crashes/"stops and restarted", the spark Streaming session is created from the checkpoint hence giving you what you want.
```

As referring to link is not encouraged in stack overflow I am going to put the sample code below. But it is essentially taken from [Spark Github example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/JavaRecoverableNetworkWordCount.java)

```
 /**
            * Counts words in text encoded with UTF8 received from the network every second. This example also
            * shows how to use lazily instantiated singleton instances for Accumulator and Broadcast so that
            * they can be registered on driver failures.
            *
            * Usage: JavaRecoverableNetworkWordCount <hostname> <port> <checkpoint-directory> <output-file>
            *   <hostname> and <port> describe the TCP server that Spark Streaming would connect to receive
            *   data. <checkpoint-directory> directory to HDFS-compatible file system which checkpoint data
            *   <output-file> file to which the word counts will be appended
            *
            * <checkpoint-directory> and <output-file> must be absolute paths
            *
            * To run this on your local machine, you need to first run a Netcat server
            *
            *      `$ nc -lk 9999`
            *
            * and run the example as
            *
            *      `$ ./bin/run-example org.apache.spark.examples.streaming.JavaRecoverableNetworkWordCount \
            *              localhost 9999 ~/checkpoint/ ~/out`
            *
            * If the directory ~/checkpoint/ does not exist (e.g. running for the first time), it will create
            * a new StreamingContext (will print "Creating new context" to the console). Otherwise, if
            * checkpoint data exists in ~/checkpoint/, then it will create StreamingContext from
            * the checkpoint data.
            *
            * Refer to the online documentation for more details.
            */
            public final class JavaRecoverableNetworkWordCount {
            private static final Pattern SPACE = Pattern.compile(" ");

            private static JavaStreamingContext createContext(String ip,
                                                                int port,
                                                                String checkpointDirectory,
                                                                String outputPath) {

                // If you do not see this printed, that means the StreamingContext has been loaded
                // from the new checkpoint
                System.out.println("Creating new context");
                File outputFile = new File(outputPath);
                if (outputFile.exists()) {
                outputFile.delete();
                }
                SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaRecoverableNetworkWordCount");
                // Create the context with a 1 second batch size
                JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(1));
                ssc.checkpoint(checkpointDirectory);

                // Create a socket stream on target ip:port and count the
                // words in input stream of \n delimited text (eg. generated by 'nc')
                JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> lines = ssc.socketTextStream(ip, port);
                JavaDStream<String> words = lines.flatMap(x -> Arrays.asList(SPACE.split(x)).iterator());
                JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordCounts = words.mapToPair(s -> new Tuple2<>(s, 1))
                    .reduceByKey((i1, i2) -> i1 + i2);

                wordCounts.foreachRDD((rdd, time) -> {
                // Get or register the blacklist Broadcast
                Broadcast<List<String>> blacklist =
                    JavaWordBlacklist.getInstance(new JavaSparkContext(rdd.context()));
                // Get or register the droppedWordsCounter Accumulator
                LongAccumulator droppedWordsCounter =
                    JavaDroppedWordsCounter.getInstance(new JavaSparkContext(rdd.context()));
                // Use blacklist to drop words and use droppedWordsCounter to count them
                String counts = rdd.filter(wordCount -> {
                    if (blacklist.value().contains(wordCount._1())) {
                    droppedWordsCounter.add(wordCount._2());
                    return false;
                    } else {
                    return true;
                    }
                }).collect().toString();
                String output = "Counts at time " + time + " " + counts;
                System.out.println(output);
                System.out.println("Dropped " + droppedWordsCounter.value() + " word(s) totally");
                System.out.println("Appending to " + outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
                Files.append(output + "\n", outputFile, Charset.defaultCharset());
                });

                return ssc;
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                if (args.length != 4) {
                System.err.println("You arguments were " + Arrays.asList(args));
                System.err.println(
                    "Usage: JavaRecoverableNetworkWordCount <hostname> <port> <checkpoint-directory>\n" +
                    "     <output-file>. <hostname> and <port> describe the TCP server that Spark\n" +
                    "     Streaming would connect to receive data. <checkpoint-directory> directory to\n" +
                    "     HDFS-compatible file system which checkpoint data <output-file> file to which\n" +
                    "     the word counts will be appended\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "In local mode, <master> should be 'local[n]' with n > 1\n" +
                    "Both <checkpoint-directory> and <output-file> must be absolute paths");
                System.exit(1);
                }

                String ip = args[0];
                int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
                String checkpointDirectory = args[2];
                String outputPath = args[3];

                // Function to create JavaStreamingContext without any output operations
                // (used to detect the new context)
                Function0<JavaStreamingContext> createContextFunc =
                    () -> createContext(ip, port, checkpointDirectory, outputPath);

                JavaStreamingContext ssc =
                JavaStreamingContext.getOrCreate(checkpointDirectory, createContextFunc);
                ssc.start();
                ssc.awaitTermination();
            }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a bug in spark version 2.1.0, seems to be fixed in spark 2.1.1 when ran  with that version.

Comment: this is specific to the new spark structured streaming, not spark streaming (dtsreams).

Comment: the bug is related to where long checkpoints are truncated when dealing with topics have large number of partitions, in my 120.